# getline function weird errors

Tags: c++, getline

I was trying do some file read/write stuff and I am unable to run my second getline command. Any ideas as to why this happens?

```
char str[80];
char substr[10];
file.open("abc.txt", fstream::in);

    file.getline(str,'\n');
      while(!file.eof())
    {
        i=0;
        while(str[i]!='\n') {substr[i] = str[i++]; }

        substr[i++]='\n'; 
        cout<<substr;

        file.getline(str,'\n');

    }
```

abc.txt

```
AND 1 2 3
NAND 4 5 6
NOR 2 3 7
XOR 1 6 8
OR 8 7 9
```

I used notepad++ to create the txt file, so am pretty sure there are CR/LF at the end of each line

Comment: can you print the contents of abc.txt?  If there is a single line, it won't ever run the loop

Comment: [`while !eof` is almost always wrong.](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.5) In this case you're actually not abusing it, but I'd still not recommend doing it this way. Also, what's wrong with `std::string`?

Comment: What does "unable to run" mean? _What_ happens?

Answer (score 1):

2nd argument of `fstream::getline` is the streamsize, not delimiter. For delimited version, you need the overloaded version. See [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/).

Answer (score -1):

Following up with my comment, try moving the file.getline command within the while loop:

```
...
while(!file.eof())
{
    file.getline(str,80,'\n');
    ...
```

Comment: I brought it in..nothing changed.

Comment: @noob i could be mistaken, but i thought getline took a length argument before the delimiter ...

Comment: @noob also in your command, you have strings of longer than 10 characters (like the nand line).  You probably want to increase the length of substr

Answer (score -1):

This works. Use getline() in the while condition and get the string delimeted by '\n' and use strcpy.

```
char str[80] = { '\0' };   
char substr[80] = { '\0' };

ifstream file;
file.open("abc.txt", fstream::in); 


int i  = 0;
while(file.getline(str, 79, '\n'))   
{   
    strncpy(substr, str, 78);    
    substr[strlen(substr)]='\n';    
    cout<<substr;      
}
```